# Next tag appearing beside Div tags instead of below them HTML

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for a class project and I'm running into an annoying issue... After my Div tags, my next heading tag `<h2>` is appearing beside my div gallery instead of below it.

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant code as text (css and html).  Nobody wants to read that screenshot.

Comment: You should include your code into the question not as a screenshot .... Please read first [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I would put the h2 within a div as so:

```
<div style='display: block'>
    <h2>what ever you want to say</h2>
</div>
```

I honestly can't say for sure as you didn't provide any code to work with. But this would be my best guess, if you have any questions comment :)

Comment: Thank you guys. I actually figured out the problem.  in my external CSS, I hat float: Left in my div element without coding a "clear" element after.  I really appreciate the help!